# How can I bring my (bootstrap) elements to the bottom of the columns without position absolute?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, position

I have 3 columns I'm working on with icons on the bottom. You can see them at the bottom of this site: https://matiny.github.io/

I want to bring the icons straight to the bottom of each grey box without using `position absolute` (which is what I'm currently using). However, without `absolute`, I don't know how to push all 3 to the bottom. They are all by default dependent on the `height` of the parent.

I've tried to use `flex`, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. `Position absolute` with a `min-height` causes issues on mobile.

It's a `bootstrap` row with 3 of these `HTML` elements inside...

```css
.gallery {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.gallery h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1.5% 0;
}

.gallery .app-box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 31rem;
  background-color: #ebedf0;
}

.gallery .app-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery .app-box .caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.gallery .app-box .name,
.gallery .app-box .description {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #0f1a30;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.gallery .app-box .name {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.gallery .app-box .description {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.gallery .app-box .icons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.gallery .app-box .icons img {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
    <a href="https://matiny.github.io/gta6/">
      <figure class="app-box">
        <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/jpgs/gallery-gta.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption class="name">
          GTA UI UPGRADES
        </figcaption>
        <div class="caption">
          <figcaption class="description">GTA Online is very detailed, but the details are presented in a confusing way. <br> I came up with various menus which are simpler to use, while maintaining the same complex functions.
          </figcaption>
          <div class="icons">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-js.svg" alt="">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-react.svg" alt="">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-sass.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the parent (card-body for me) should have `display : flex` ... and inside, you can have the `mt-auto` class to set the margin-top automatically...

below **snippet** is from a code which I did a little while back, it can help in your case

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-flex">

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-colum">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn customBtn mt-auto">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-flex">

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-colum">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn customBtn mt-auto">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 d-flex">

      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-colum text-center">
          <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn customBtn mt-auto">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gallery {
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
}

.gallery h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 1.5% 0;
}

.gallery .app-box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 31rem;
  background-color: #ebedf0;
}

.gallery .app-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery .app-box .caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.gallery .app-box .name,
.gallery .app-box .description {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #0f1a30;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.gallery .app-box .name {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.gallery .app-box .description {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.gallery .app-box .icons {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.gallery .app-box .icons img {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-12">
    <a href="https://matiny.github.io/gta6/">
      <figure class="app-box">
        <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/jpgs/gallery-gta.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption class="name">
          GTA UI UPGRADES
        </figcaption>
        <div class="caption">
          <figcaption class="description">GTA Online is very detailed, but the details are presented in a confusing way. <br> I came up with various menus which are simpler to use, while maintaining the same complex functions.
          </figcaption>
          <div class="icons">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-js.svg" alt="">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-react.svg" alt="">
            <img src="https://matiny.github.io/images/svgs/icon-sass.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>

      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

add `margin-top: auto`  to `.gallery .app-box .icons` OR add `mt-auto` bootstrap class to `icons` `div`